# By updating my job email settings, I have accidentally merged 2 accounts, how do I undo the merge?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts, undo

A few years ago, I created a new account on SO with a new gmail address, and stopped using my old one which was associated with my personal email address.

Now since then, I only go with the new one, on which I only answer questions, and which I use on SO chat.

Today, as I was updating my job settings, I accidentally put my old gmail address to be reached out on by recruiters, and both account got merged.

Now, the account i've been using these past few years is no longer accessible, Which is something I honestly don't want.

I don't really care about the old account (if it's deleted or not), nor the reps I gained after the merge, all I want is to retrieve the account I used to go with.

Is it possible to undo the merge and retrieve back my "new" (2y old) account?

Comment: If anything you need to contact the team. There is a link at the bottom of each page. Nothing you or we can do for now and I'm not even sure if undo-ing a completed merge is even possible.

Comment: I filed a support ticket now waiting for their reply. If the merge undoing is indeed impossible that would be very unfortunate... Had I only got a message warning me about a merge possibility I wouldn't have performed that update...

Comment: What exactly is missing? Merge does not remove anything, only, well, merging two accounts into one. You can edit your new, merged, profile, and put back whatever you want in there, including changing the display name to that of the "old" account.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Nothing is missing, what I actually don't want is all the questions / answers dragged from my old account. I would like to have my "clean" 2y old account back (the account I made when I decided to start contributing to SO).

Comment: Updating your SO Jobs profile shouldn't merge accounts (unless it notified you that it would?) It would be worth reporting this as a bug report too IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't undo the merge. Even moderators can't undo account merge. I believe Stack Exchange staff can, but it requires manual intervention (i.e. no "undo merge" button") which takes lots of time and efforts.

The reason is that unlike posts deletion which is ["soft"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soft_deletion), account deletion is ["hard"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hard_deletion). Hence, to get the data reversed, they need to look in backups, etc.

Personally I don't think SE staff should spend time on such things. You can try and ask them anyway by going to the "Contact" page linked in the footer, and choosing "Other" as the reason in the contact form, pledging your case. But like I said, chances for this to work are pretty low.

If you have posts that you really really don't want to show in your profile anymore, you can ask to disassociate them from your account. If it's only one or two, just flag each and ask for this, otherwise submit contact form, choose "Other" and explain what posts you want disassociated and why. This action is trivial for SE staff, so they're more likely to respond and do it.

Comment: Understood, Thanks! I'll take my shot :)

Comment: FYI - the support replied and looks like it's not possible to un-merge, or mass disassociate the old content from my actual account, so I'll restart with a fresh account with the email address I'm willing to use.

Comment: Sorry to hear... good luck! :)

Comment: Appreciate it, Thank you! :)